# How do I add Inspect Element right click into an electron app? (Just like in Google Chrome)

Tags: electron

I'm trying to include Inspect element right click into my electron app, I found a previous post about this but this is 4 years old and I don't know where to include this. I already managed to get devtools to open automatically but now I want to add right click inspect element. My question is.

How and where do I add inspect element as right click to work globally throughout my app and how do I make dev-tools open with a shortcut. currently I automatically open Devtools in the main.js script but when I click it away I got no way of bringing it back. Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Add the following code to your window's **renderer process** code.
Note that you may have to adapt the first two lines, depending on which API elements are already defined...

```
const { remote, webFrame } = require ('electron');
const { getCurrentWebContents, Menu, MenuItem } = remote;
//
let rightClickPosition;
//
const contextMenu = new Menu ();
const menuItem = new MenuItem
(
    {
        label: 'Inspect Element',
        click: () =>
        {
            let factor = webFrame.getZoomFactor ();
            let x = Math.round (rightClickPosition.x * factor);
            let y = Math.round (rightClickPosition.y * factor);
            getCurrentWebContents ().inspectElement (x, y);
        }
    }
);
contextMenu.append (menuItem);
//
window.addEventListener
(
    'contextmenu',
    (event) =>
    {
        event.preventDefault ();
        rightClickPosition = { x: event.x, y: event.y };
        contextMenu.popup ();
    },
    false
);
```

References:

- [webFrame.getZoomFactor()](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/web-frame#webframegetzoomfactor)
- [contents.inspectElement(x, y)](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#contentsinspectelementx-y)
- [menu.popup(options)](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/menu#menupopupoptions)

As for how to have devTools open with a shortcut, this would automatically happen if your menu bar contains a submenu with a menu item whose `role` is `toggledevtools`. For instance, in your **main process** code, adding this to your menu template would provide a `Toggle Developer Tools` menu item with standard keyboard shortcut:

```
{
    label: "Developer",
    submenu:
    [
        { role: 'reload' },
        { role: 'toggledevtools' }
    ]
}
```

Reference: [Menu Item Roles](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/menu-item#roles)

**UPDATE**:

It appears there is a more powerful and flexible way of handling a contextual menu at the `webContents` level, by listening to a `'context-menu'` event, documented since Electron 1.0.2.

One important feature is that the zoom factor doesn't need to be taken into account any more, the `x` and `y` coordinates returned in `params` are just always right.

Reference: [webContents Event: 'context-menu'](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#event-context-menu)

Here is some alternative **renderer process** code using this method:

```
const { getCurrentWebContents, Menu, MenuItem } = require ('electron').remote;
//
let webContents = getCurrentWebContents ();
//
let rightClickPosition;
//
const contextMenu = new Menu ();
const menuItem = new MenuItem
(
    {
        label: 'Inspect Element',
        click: () =>
        {
            webContents.inspectElement (rightClickPosition.x, rightClickPosition.y);
        }
    }
);
contextMenu.append (menuItem);
//
webContents.on
(
    'context-menu',
    (event, params) =>
    {
        rightClickPosition = { x: params.x, y: params.y };
        contextMenu.popup ();
    }
);
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the help, I got a question though. I'm pretty new to electron. is my main rendering process the place where i open devtools? because when I start up my app it instantly opens devtools so I'd assume it is. Also I get an error that says this
`Uncaught exception:
       TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'getCurrnetWebContents' of 'undefined' or 'null', at Object.<anonymous>` I don't get what this means either :( I think I put it in the right spot.

Comment: In Electron, there is no such thing as a *main rendering process*; instead, there is one (and only one) *main process* which is creating the application menus and windows, and one *renderer process* for each created browser window (often one main window only). DevTools, which are part of each browser window, can be automatically opened at creation time by using the `mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()` method during development, but this is usually commented out for public release.

Comment: It seems that the relevant code is not called from a proper *renderer process*, since `remote` appears `undefined`... Also, there is a typo in your code: `getCurrnetWebContents`should be `getCurrentWebContents` instead...

Comment: One good start from the Electron Application Architecture page is: [Main and Renderer Processes](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/application-architecture#main-and-renderer-processes)